# Module assignment in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, module

How will we assign a particular module for  particular page in joomla 3.0? I  have no particular menu  item for that page?I know that if i have a particular menu ,then assign that module to that particular menu item,but i dont have menu

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

- You cannot assign a module to a URL link. This is because URL links do not have Itemids assigned to them.
- You cannot directly assign modules to pages that are only linked via
  content (for example, a link from one article to another) or other,
  non-menu modules (for example, a link to an article from a module),
  because these also do not have Itemids. One work-around for this
  problem is to have an unpublished menu that contains links to the
  items you wish to link through non-menus. This will create an itemid
  that can be included in the url you link to.

Source: [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_assign_a_module_to_specific_pages%3F)

Answer (score 0):

In only case that this page is an article or a component that you could load content via plugin you could use loadposition / loadmodule method.

[Here is the official documentantion](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F) how you could do that.

Hope this helps